# What's the difficulty to hit when the target is not defending (not surprise round)?

Tags: combat, attack, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Building on [this question about attack/defence](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138151/whats-the-dice-penalty-if-you-attack-and-defend-against-multiple-opponents):

My players have decided that dog-piling one opponent at a time is the way to go in hand to hand combat. So using the example of Katarina and her 3 attackers from the core rules, let's call the attackers Tom, Dick and Harry.

1. Katarina attacks Tom and chooses not to split her dice pool. They Both roll attack rolls.
2. Katarina therefore gets no defence against Dick.
3. And Katarina gets no defence against Harry.

**Question: What is the Difficulty for Dick and Harry to hit Katarina?**

If it was a Surprise Attack, it would be Difficulty 1. But this is after any surprise round has been and gone. Still Difficulty 1? Difficulty 0?

(And yes, I know that the PCs who are dogpiling Katarina will get no defence against another NPC attacking them. They seem willing to take that risk!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A target that isn’t defending presents a difficulty of 1. (VtM 5E Core, p.302) There's always the chance that Dick or Harry could fail to connect.

Comment: My copy of the core rules only says Difficulty 1 for ranged attacks against stationary targets on page 302. I guess I can use that, but I was after an official answer on close combat. (Also, it would have been nice if they had printed a relevant rule in the Simple Combat section).

Comment: @DrBob The text in that section suggests that "lacks a defense pool" and "Difficulty 1" are equivalent, just as is the case with surprise.